# Change support SearchView theme

Tags: android, android-widget, android-support-library, android-styles, searchview

In my app I have a SearchView that uses the support.v7 library because of compatibility.

The problem is that, in a device with API 11 or higher, when I open the searchview i get the support api style and only after I search for something the style changes to my application style.

I want the theme in the newest APIs to be always like the second image. Already tried other themes but the result is always the same.

Style when the searchview expands:[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXXZd.png).

Style after a search:[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaxTa.png)

options_menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:malfriends="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:title="@string/search_title"
    malfriends:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    malfriends:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/logoff"
    android:title="@string/logout"
    malfriends:showAsAction="never"/>

</menu>
```

searchable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:hint="@string/search_hint"
android:label="@string/app_name" android:searchSuggestAuthority=
"com.dandrex.malfriends.controller.provider.SearchFriendsProvider"
android:searchSuggestSelection=" ?" />
```

My activity class

```
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;

...

public class FeedTabActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
    ActionBar.TabListener
```

onCreateOptionsMenu

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search)
                .getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
                .getSearchableInfo(new ComponentName(
                        FeedTabActivity.this, FeedTabActivity.class)));
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    } else {
        MenuItem itemCompat = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
        searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(itemCompat);
    }
    return true;
}
```